# Finding rows of dataframe with minimum values with same index,python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with the index set to be the dates. I need to find the row (set of parameters for each month) where the value of the sensor is the minimum. 
The codes I tried are as following:

```
1.optimization = r.loc[[r.index.month == month]]  
  optimization=r.loc[r['Sensors'].idxmin()]
2.optimization=DataFrame(r.resample('M').Sensors.min()) 
3.optimization=r.loc[r['Sensors'].idxmin()]
4.optimization= r.loc[r.groupby([r.index.month == month])["Sensors"].idxmin()]
```

My datat farme:

```
Index          ACH_Base        Am          Energy                  Sensors  

2017_01_31       0.3           0.9         2.2989e+11          39087428391.1

2017_01_31       0.5           0.8         2.29892e+11         37142574944.9

....
2017_02_28       0.7           0.9         2.40001e+11         38568420286.9

2017_02_28       0.3           0.7         2.7136+11           36945759284.8

....
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) for get minimal values per `month`, compare with `Sensors` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y_%m_%d')

df = df[df['Sensors'] == df.resample('M')['Sensors'].transform('min')]
print (df)
            ACH_Base   Am       Energy       Sensors
2017-01-31       0.5  0.8  2.29892e+11  3.714257e+10
2017-02-28       0.3  0.7    2.7136+11  3.694576e+10
```

Comment: @ezrael thanks for the solution. I still get the whole dataframe! But one question, I did not use pd.to_datetime. Can be that the reason?

Comment: @MaryamNahid - what is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: @MaryamNahid - need datetimeindex if want month values

Comment: its the dates: 2017-01-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31',
               '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31',
               '2017-01-31', '2017-01-31',
               ...
               '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30',
               '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30',
               '2017-06-30', '2017-06-30']

Comment: @MaryamNahid and what is `print (df.index.dtype)` ?

Comment: it is : datetime64[ns]

Comment: @MaryamNahid - OK, so it is good. But still dont understand why get all rows. with sample it working nice. Are data confidental?

Comment: @MaryamNahid - so can you send me your code and mainly data file to my email in my profile?